# Radon-Nikodým property of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am wondering whether $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ has the Radon-Nikodým property. Of course $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$ does, but I was unable to find out whether (e.g.) duals of spaces with the R-N property have the R-N property themselves.

UPDATE: A Banach space is Asplund if and only if its dual has the Radon-Nikodým property. On the other hand, a separable space is Asplund if and only if its dual is separable, too. This rules out the possibility that $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ has the R-N property. But is there any other (more) elementary argument for this assertion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since a closed subspace of a space with RNP clearly also has RNP, in order to get the requested elementary example, it suffices to display a measure on the unit interval with values in $c_0$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure but whose 
derivative does not take its values there.  This can be done via  the usual trick with the sequence $\frac 1 n \cos n x$.  I guess this example is in the classical text by Diestel and Uhl which is probably still the best reference for the RNP.

Answer (score 7):

For dual spaces, there is an important  characterization: $X^*$ has the Radon-Nikodym property if and only if $X$ is Asplund (its separable subspaces have separable duals). Of course, $\ell_1$ is not Asplund.

Comment: (I see the update just after posting)

Comment: Uh, thanks a lot. I found exactly the same answer simultaneously. I am not familiar with the theory of Asplund spaces, so why is $\ell^1$ "obviously" no Asplund space? For the reason I mention or is there some simpler explanation?

Comment: Separable dual spaces are ok (Dunford-Pettis theorem).

Comment: András, I do not understand this comment, either. This shows that $\ell^1$ has the R-N property, of course. But why does anything about $\ell^\infty$, or weighted version thereof, follow?

Comment: It does not. You asked for a condition when a dual space has RN, and this came to my mind.

Comment: ok, now I understand.

Comment: $l^\infty$ has a subspace isometric to $l^1$.  Indeed $l^\infty$ has a subspace isometric to any given separable space.

Answer (score 1):

See Proposition 1.2.9 in [Arendt-Batty-Hieber-Neubrander](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-3-0348-0086-0). (I look at the first edition now)

Comment: András, I am not sure I understand. That Proposition is about $c_0$, right?

Comment: See the later answer by jbc.

Answer (score 0):

This post is concerned with *"whether duals of spaces with the R-N property have the R-N property themselves"*.

Every reflexive Banach space $X$ and its dual $X^{*}$ have RNP. For a non-reflexive (but quasi-reflexive) example, James space $J$ and its dual $J^{*}$ (generally all higher duals) have RNP.